# JFrame to JApplet doesnt work in browser

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet

I have a Java program with a Swing GUI im trying to make it work as a JApplet on a HTML file when I test it on Eclipse launch it as a Applet it works but when I compile it using javac. I get all these files Reverser.class, Reverser$1.class, Reverser$2.class, Reverser$3.class and Reverser$4.class. It doesnt work an help

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<applet code="Reverser.class", height="500" width="800">
</applet>
</BODY>
</HTML>


package Applets;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Reverser extends JApplet
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //All Swing elements declared here
    private JTextArea userinput, useroutput;
    private JScrollPane sbr_userinput, sbr_useroutput;
    private JButton runButton, clearButton, homeButton;

    private String text; //User input stored here
    private String reversed_text; //reversed text stored here

    public void init() 
    {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                setContentPane(GUI());
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            System.err.println("createGUI didn't complete successfully");
        }
    }

    public Container GUI() //Main GUI container here
    {
        JPanel totalGUI = new JPanel(); //Main panel set here
        totalGUI.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 3, 3)); //Main panel layout set here.

        JPanel lPanel = new JPanel(); //Left panel made here
        lPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 3 , 3)); //Left panel layout set here
        totalGUI.add(lPanel); // Left Panel added to main panel.

        JPanel rPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1, 3 , 3)); //Right panel made here and its layout set here aswell
        totalGUI.add(rPanel);//Right panel added to main panel.

        //Userinput TextArea made here 
        userinput = new JTextArea("Welcome to wicky waky text reverser!!!" + "\n" + "Enter your sentence HERE man!!!!");
        userinput.setEditable(true); //TextArea set to editable
        userinput.setLineWrap(true);
        userinput.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        lPanel.add(userinput);//TextArea added to left panel

        useroutput = new JTextArea(); //useroutput TextArea set here
        useroutput.setEditable(false); //TextArea set to not editable
        useroutput.setLineWrap(true);
        useroutput.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        lPanel.add(useroutput); //TextArea added to the left panel

        //Scroll bar made here
        sbr_userinput = new JScrollPane(userinput, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, 
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        sbr_userinput.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        lPanel.add(sbr_userinput); //Scroll bar added to left panel

        //Scroll bar made here
        sbr_useroutput = new JScrollPane(useroutput, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, 
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        sbr_useroutput.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        lPanel.add(sbr_useroutput); //Scroll bar added to the left panel

        runButton = new JButton("RUN"); //Button made here
        runButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() //Action Listener made here
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                text = userinput.getText(); //Get userinput here
                reversed_text = reverser(text); //reverser method called here
                try {
                    userinput.setText("");
                    userinput.setText("Processed");
                    Thread.sleep(500); //sleep 0.5 sec
                    //Print out all output here
                    useroutput.setText("Your sentence is ==> " + text + "\n" + "\n"
                    + "Your reversed sentence is ==>  " + reversed_text);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) 
                {

                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("working");
            }
        });
        rPanel.add(runButton); //Add button to right panel

        clearButton = new JButton("CLEAR"); //New button made here
        clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                userinput.setText(""); //Set userinput to empty
                useroutput.setText(""); //Set useroutput to empty
                System.out.println("cleared");
            }
        });
        rPanel.add(clearButton); //Add button to right panel

        homeButton = new JButton("HOME"); //New button made here
        homeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() //Action Listener added here
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
            }
        });
        rPanel.add(homeButton); //add button to right panel

        totalGUI.setOpaque(true);
        return totalGUI; // return totalGUI
    }

    public static String reverser(String text)
        {
            //"text" is now put in the object "reverse_text", StringBuffer used so I can use the reverse method.
            StringBuffer reverse_text = new StringBuffer(text);

            String reversed = reverse_text.reverse().toString();   //reverse and toString methods used.

            return reversed; // return revered
        }
}
```

Comment: *"I have a Java program with a Swing GUI im trying to make it work as a JApplet on a HTML file"*  For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.  I.E. don't convert the frame to an applet, simply launch the frame using JWS.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the package name in your applet. Consider changing

```
code="Reverser.class"
```

to

```
code="Applets.Reverser.class"
```

and making sure that the class file is in the Applets subdirectory relative to the HTML file. Or even better, create a jar file.

Also you need to post the error messages that the browser is giving you. You could have a version incompatibility for all we know.

Comment: are you saying I should make a folder called Applets put all the class files in side including the HTML file and the run it ? And about jar file i read up about it but I dont understand the manifest file thing

Comment: @user1898552: Yes make a folder called Applets since that's the name of the package. The HTML file should not be in the Applets folder. Also you need to post the error messages that the browser is giving you. You could have a version incompatibility for all we know.

Comment: Ok I got it working a made a jar file like you said and in the HTML i put down code="Applets.Reverser.class" archive="Reverser.jar". However  lets say I had 3 other programs and a main GUI java class file and I compiled all of them and I multiple class file I then create a jar file. In my main GUI java source could how to I open another applet from a button

Comment: @user1898552: typically if your application required a second window, you'd open a JDialog from a button press, not another JApplet. This would be the subject of a different question, but before doing this, ask yourself if you absolutely require a second window or if the user's view could be updated in a different way such as via the CardLayout.

Comment: Yes was reading another topic and basically you can use the card layout. Once the user click on the button another applet is visible and the current one is destroyed. the code that I got from the topic is this but I dont know how to implement this in my code:Class applet2 = Class.forName("Applet2");
Applet appletToLoad = (Applet)applet2.newInstance();
appletToLoad.setStub(this);
setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0));
add(appletToLoad);
appletToLoad.init();
appletToLoad.start();